# SQL Query to return Unmatched Rows from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've 2 tables tblEmp1 and tblEmp2 from which i need to extract non matching rows of tblEmp1 by comparing tblEmp2.

select * from tblEmp1

```
EmpMasterID     DeptID  MngrID      TEMPID      Salary1         Salary2         DOJ         
46              3       995         559         1000000000      1000000000      2016-12-31      
47              3       999         556         2500000000      2500000000      2016-12-31      
48              3       994         165         1500000000      1500000000      2016-12-31          
49              3       998         566         7500000000      7500000000      2016-12-31          
50              3       1049        562         9500000000      9500000000      2016-12-31
```

select * from tblEmp2

```
EmpID   DeptName    DeptID  MngrID  TEMPID      Salary1         Salary2         DOJ                         
84      XYZ         3       994     165         1500000000      1500000000      2016-12-31  
85      XYZ         3       995     559         1000000000      1000000000      2016-12-31      
86      XYZ         3       999     556         2500000000      2500000000      2016-12-31
```

As you all can see above for DeptID = 3, MngrID = 994, 995, 999 and TempID = 165, 559, 556 i have matching salary1 and salary2 with DOJ = '2016-12-31'.

My requirement is i should extract only those records from first table which are not present in tblEmp2 table for DFeptID = 3 and DOJ = '2016-12-31'
i.e., my Query should return the ending 2 rows from tblEmp1 table

```
EmpMasterID     DeptID  MngrID      TEMPID      Salary1         Salary2         DOJ                     
49              3       998         566         7500000000      7500000000      2016-12-31          
50              3       1049        562         9500000000      9500000000      2016-12-31
```

Since they are not there in tblEmp2 table where DeptID = 3 and DOJ = '2016-12-31'

This is what i've trid till now

```
select t1.EmpMasterID, t1.DeptID, t1.MngrID, t1.TEMPID, t1.Salary1, t1.Salary2, t1.DOJ  
from tblEmp1 as t1
left outer join tblEmp2 as t2
on  t1.DeptID = t2.DeptID, t1.MngrID = t2.MngrID, t1.TEMPID = t2.TEMPID, t1.DOJ = t2.DOJ
where t1.DeptID = 3 and t1.DOJ = '2016-12-31' and t2.MngrID is null and t2.TEMPID is null
```

IMPORTANT: I forget to mention that tblEmp2 table i need to filter based on DeptName too... i.e., tblEmp1.DeptID = 3, tblEmp2.DeptName = 'XYZ' and tblEmp1.DOJ = '2016-12-31' should be the search/filter condition.

Comment: Which column is your base for comparison? MngrId, TempID or what?

Comment: BOTH, IF ANY ONE IS DIFFERENT

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below script. Change the ',' in your on condition with AND operator.

```
   SELECT t1.EmpMasterID, t1.DeptID, t1.MngrID, t1.TEMPID, t1.Salary1, t1.Salary2, t1.DOJ  
   FROM tblEmp1 as t1
       left outer join tblEmp2 as t2
          on  t1.DeptID = t2.DeptID and t1.MngrID = t2.MngrID and t1.TEMPID = t2.TEMPID and t1.DOJ = t2.DOJ
            AND    t2.DeptName = 'XYZ' -- AND t1.Salary1=t2.Salary1 AND t1.Salary2=t2.Salary2 --(include these columns if you wanted to compare salary)
   WHERE t1.DeptID = 3 and t1.DOJ = '2016-12-31' 
         and t2.DeptId is null
```

OR use **NOT EXISTS**..

```
 SELECT t1.EmpMasterID, t1.DeptID, t1.MngrID, t1.TEMPID, t1.Salary1, t1.Salary2, t1.DOJ  
   FROM tblEmp1 as t1
       WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                        FROM  tblEmp2 as t2
                        WHERE  t1.DeptID = t2.DeptID and t1.MngrID = t2.MngrID and t1.TEMPID = t2.TEMPID and t1.DOJ = t2.DOJ 
                            -- AND t1.Salary1=t2.Salary1 AND t1.Salary2=t2.Salary2 --(include these columns if you wanted to compare salary)
                                 )
       AND t1.DeptID = 3 and t1.DOJ = '2016-12-31'
```

Comment: What is the difference in expected output and the result of the above query?

Comment: You have to include the condition 'tblEmp2.DeptName = 'XYZ' ' in the on clause of the left join.. If you include it in the where condition it will act as an inner join..

Answer (score 0):

```
select  *
from    tblEmp1 t1
join    (

    select  DeptID, MngrID, TempID
    from    tblEmp1
except
    select  DeptID, MngrID, TempID
    from    tblEmp2
) t2 on t1.DeptId = t2.DeptId and t1. MngrId = t2.MngrId and t1.TempID = t2.TempID
```

Answer (score 0):

I run this:

```
;WITH tblEmp1 AS (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
(46,              3,       995,         559,         1000000000,      1000000000,      '2016-12-31'),
(47,              3,       999,         556,         2500000000,      2500000000,      '2016-12-31'),
(48,              3,       994,         165,         1500000000,      1500000000,      '2016-12-31'),       
(49,              3,       998,         566,         7500000000,      7500000000,      '2016-12-31'),
(50,              3,       1049,        562,         9500000000,      9500000000,      '2016-12-31')
) as t(EmpMasterID,DeptID,MngrID,TEMPID,Salary1,Salary2,DOJ)
), tblEmp2 AS (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
(84,      'XYZ',         3,       994,     165,         1500000000,      1500000000,      '2016-12-31'),
(85,      'XYZ',         3,       995,     559,         1000000000,      1000000000,      '2016-12-31'),
(86,      'XYZ',         3,       999,     556,         2500000000,      2500000000,      '2016-12-31')
) as t(EmpID,DeptName,DeptID,MngrID,TEMPID,Salary1,Salary2,DOJ )
)

SELECT e1.*
FROM tblEmp1 e1
LEFT JOIN tblEmp2 e2
    ON e1.DeptID = e2.DeptID 
        AND e1.MngrID = e2.MngrID
        AND e1.TEMPID = e2.TEMPID
        AND e1.DOJ = e2.DOJ
where e1.DeptID = 3 and e1.DOJ = '2016-12-31'
    AND e2.MngrID IS NULL AND e2.TEMPID IS NULL
```

And get this:

```
EmpMasterID DeptID  MngrID  TEMPID  Salary1     Salary2     DOJ
49          3       998     566     7500000000  7500000000  2016-12-31
50          3       1049    562     9500000000  9500000000  2016-12-31
```

Exactly the rows you need, almost same query as you post. What suppose to be a problem?